# missing rows with cout for 2d vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, stdout, cout

I am quite insane, and cannot interpret what happens here.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 0, j = 0, m = 3, n = 3;
    vector<vector<int> > vvi(3, vector<int>(3, 1));

    // why the following code outputs only single row, 
    // i.e.,"111" from vvi[0]? what about vvi[1], vvi[2]?
    for(; i < m; ++i) {
        for(; j< n; ++j) {
            cout << vvi[i][j];
        }
    }
    // any difference from the code below? 
    // for(int i=0; i < m; ++i) {
    //   for(int j= 0; j< n; ++j) {
    //      cout << vvi[i][j];
    //   }
    // }
}
```

Comment: The commented-out code is, of course, correct. And it illustrates why it's helpful to initialize values **where they're first used**. There's no reason for defining `i` and `j` at the top of `main`. And while I'm commenting on the code, replace the two `3`s in the definition of `vvi` with `m` and `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first iteration of the outer loop the counter variable `j` gets incremented from `0` to `n`, but since it never gets reset to `0` it stays at `n`, thus the inner loop condition `j < n` is false for all subsequent iterations of the outer loop. Therefore the `cout` will never be executed again.

In the code you commented out, `j` gets reset (reinitialized) to `0` for every iteration of the outer loop and therefore it will print all rows.

Comment: aha, yeah, my brain definitely gets stuck here. you guys all beat me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

In the first one, when `vvi[0]` is done, `j` is `3`.
When it goes to `vvi[1]` `j` is still `3` so `j < n` is false.

In the second one, when the outer loop starts the second iteration, `j` will be set to `0` again.

This code is equivalent with the second one(in the result):

```
    for(; i < m; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j< n; ++j) {
            cout << vvi[i][j];
        }
    }
```